# Can't locate files from raw folder

Tags: android, resources, audio

I added some mp3 files in my raw folder using drag and drop. But I can't locate them when using R.raw... code. I don't know why. My filenames are all letters and no spaces. Here is a printscreen of it.

[image]

Do you have any ideas on what is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: you have two files with same name(menu) in raw folder ?

Comment: Try to clean your project. This can help.

Comment: clean and build project may be that may help you, also check @ρяσѕρєяK K point

Comment: Yes I have two menus. Thanks! :)